# MYSQL Advanced Wild Card Search

Tags: mysql, regex, wildcard

Say my mysql table has a field name with a value of
**record 1:** Steve ABCDEF data
**record 2:** Steve C data
**record 3:** Steve BCF data
**record 4:** Steve F C data

I want to search for results that contain something like "Steve %C% "
Which would bring up record 1 2 & 3
**I don't however, want it to pull up record 4!**

Because I only want the wild card to go to the space character. Once it hits space, I want it to stop searching.

So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'Steve \*[C]\*'
```

This obviously doesn't work though, because it will bring up all the records (including record 4), and I only want it if it has the "C" before the space, ie. records 1, 2, & 3.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'Steve [^[:space:]]*C'
```